# onClick and onChange doesn't fire on radio buttons for safari in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, safari

What is the best practice for handling events on Radio Buttons in ReactJS? 
Radio Buttons are not working in safari
The documentation shows using "onClick" on the "Handling Events" documentation and it shows using "onChange" in the "Forms" documentation. onChange only fires one time on Radio Buttons, so I am currently using onClick for them.

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Maybe a cut and paste of the error from the console?

Answer (score 0):

Example with checkbox. With radio buttons I assume you have a radio group.

constructor :

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        agreements: false,
    };
    this.handleSwitchChange = this.handleSwitchChange.bind(this);
}
```

In the function handleSwitchChange

```
handleSwitchChange(event){
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
```

And in  the render function :

```
           <div className="col-xs-12">
                <label className="label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="agreements" checked={this.state.agreements} value={this.state.agreements} onClick={this.handleSwitchChange}/>
                    <span></span>
                    &nbsp;I agree to the term
                </label>
            </div>
```

Edit : handleSwitchChange function is not in the render function ;)